# Xamarin Studio fails to execute code with login shell in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, d, xamarin-studio

I'm new to Xamarin on the Mac, and I'm running into some issues running my code. I don't think it should matter, but I'm using the [D language plugin](http://mono-d.alexanderbothe.com/) to develop my code.

When Terminal is set to `Shells open with: Default login shell` (which is zsh in my case, but bash results in the same issue), hitting the execute button causes Xamarin Studio to pop up a Terminal window which closes before it can do anything, and then Xamarin Studio reports `Cannot execute "blah". ScriptError`. I added an infinite loop at the beginning of my program to make sure the shell isn't exiting because the program terminated quickly, and sure enough the program seems not to be starting at all.

If I instead tell Terminal `Shells open with: Command (complete path): /opt/local/bin/zsh`, the terminal happily opens up and the window is named correctly  as "Xamarin Studio External Console" but of course nothing is executed except for the shell itself.

Any way to debug or fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop/XamarinStudio uses xterm by default. Dunno if that piece of info might help.